# AutoFill for iOS Apps for faster signup Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, autofill, sign

I would like to find a solution for iOS with auto-filling the remaining fields after entering, e.g. name or surname. Is there such a solution in Swift for iOS users?

Comment: I meant data from the app, f.e. for data from signup in another app.

Comment: iOS apps are sandboxed. You cannot directly access data from other apps

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround is to use proper `keyboardContentType` for different text fields in your form as mentioned here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1649656-textcontenttype

It will not auto-fill all the fields, but this seems like the only way where system can suggest auto-fill values for users to select.

> When you provide this information about the content you expect users
>   to enter in a text input area, the system can in some cases
>   automatically select an appropriate keyboard and improve keyboard
>   corrections and proactive integration with other text input
>   opportunities.

which looks like this:

[image]

(Image from https://www.iosdev.recipes/text-input/configuring-uitextfield-with-uitextcontenttype-and-friends/)

Comment: This isn't even a workaround. This is just best practice, and will let the OS help you.

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks! Glad to know my answer was helpful ;)